# Split cells into 2 columns when any number

Tags: vba, excel, split

I can see numerous posts around this topic but none that specifically solves the problem I have.

I have a string that has text and numbers. I need to split the string into 2 columns when it first sees a number.

**Example**:

```
Ballyvic Boru5/6
First Drift2/1
Sizing Cusimanoin15/2
```

**Becomes:**

[image: pic]

Comment: use regex https://regex101.com/r/aY3hZ1/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple formula to find the first number, along with `LEFT` and `MID` to split the string.

**Part 1**:

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890"))-1)
```

**Part 2**:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")),99)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a regex method:

> You must set a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x`, where x.x is the highest version you have (mine is 5.5)

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitCells()

    Dim RegEx As New RegExp, i As Long, tempStr As String

    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(([a-z]*\s?)*\D)(\d.*)"
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            If RegEx.Test(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
                tempStr = .Cells(i, 1)
                .Cells(i, 1) = RegEx.Replace(tempStr, "$1")
                .Cells(i, 2) = RegEx.Replace(tempStr, "$3")
           End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

---

### Breaking down the Regular Expression:

```
(([a-z]*\s?)*\D)(\d.*)
```

`[a-z]*` matches any character in the alphabet, with the `*` multiplier for unlimited occurances

`\s?` Matches any whitespace character, with the `?` multiplier to match 0-1 occurances (meaning there may or may not be a white space

Both of the above is enclosed in a grouping `()`, followed by another `*` to match 0-unlimited occurances

`\D` This excludes all digits

The above is enclosed in a group with the first `(([..])*\D)`

We have our final group: `(\d.*)`, which matches the first digit and everything else afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pair functions you can use on the worksheet (as opposed to having to run a VBA procedure to 'fix' the cells one time):

```
Public Function splitNum1(str As String) As String
    Dim p
    For p = 1 To Len(str)
        If Mid(str, p, 1) Like "#" Then Exit For
    Next
    splitNum1 = Left(str, p - 1)
End Function

Public Function splitNum2(str As String) As String
    splitNum2 = Right(str, Len(str) - Len(splitNum1(str)))
End Function
```

- `splitNum1` returns the string on the "left" side of the number.
- `splitNum2` returns the string beginning with the first nummber.

[image: correc]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  SplitNum1 works perfectly but SplitNum2 is not returning the number section (includes some letters as well).

Comment: @Seale - Whoops, you can tell I was in a rush; even my example screenshot showed the error!  Sorry about that, I've corrected it.